# Why touch menu would exit the app?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I touch the menu button to open the activity navigation drawer, the app would simply exit! the only message I have in the monitor log:

```
ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

How can I debug that? no errors in the log..

Comment: Try to override method `finish` in your activity. Add some logs, or make a break point, and then in call stack look, where this method called

Comment: I will try that right way..

Comment: post your `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Comment: Thanks, I've found the problem